# Arrange rows by pairs in R based on two columns

Tags: r, datatable

I need to order data table by pairs of users who sent messages. Currently, the data looks like this:
[image: data]

I want to rearrange rows so that I can see how many messages users exchanged between each other. If one user sent a message, but the other one did not respond, I need to have a value of 0 in column Messages_sent.

[image: table]

As a next step, I need to calculate conversation length between two users, therefore, sum Messages_sent for every two lines.

Please advice how I can rearrange data table!

Comment: Hi, It will be much easier to help you if you include your data as a text, not as an image. As for the question itself it's not very clear. For example if there are only 2 users in your system what would you like to see in the output in these 2 cases: One user send 5 messages, the other user replies on 3. One user sends 3 messages the other one does not reply. How many records you want to see in both scenarios and what should be in each field?

Comment: Hi! I want to have two rows for each pair of users who communicated. In one row you can see how many messages one user send to another, in the second row the opposite. There are cases when the message was sent, but user did not reply. In that case, the value in one of the rows will be 0.

Comment: @Katia,   I tried the following, but it does not work:  for (i in 1:nrow(dt.messages)) {
  dt.messages$message_received[i] <- dt.messages$message_sent[dt.messages$to_id == dt.messages$from_id[i] & 
                                                                 dt.messages$from_id == dt.messages$to_id[i] ] 
  }

Comment: Hi Yuliia, I added some suggestions how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr, to get the table given in your description, this code should work. But if you want to sum the counts in both directions the first line contains all you may want.

```
df <- merge(df,df
  ,by.x=c("from_id","to_id"),by.y=c("to_id","from_id")
  ,all.x=TRUE,all.y=TRUE)
df <- mutate(df,Messages_sent.x=coalesce(Messages_sent.x,0),
                Messages_sent.y=coalesce(Messages_sent.y,0))
df$row <- 1:nrow(df)
rbind(select(df,-Messages_sents.y) %>%
        rename(Messages_sent=Messages_sent.x),
      select(df,-Messages_sent.x) %>% 
        rename(Messages_sent=Messages_sent.y,from_id=to_id,to_id=from_id)
     ) %>% arrange(row) %>% select(-row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps using base R functions:

```
df <- data.frame(from_id=c(624227,624227,624227,624227,624227,624227,667255,667255,667255,7134655,713465),
                 to_id = c(352731,693915,184455,771100,503940,91558,626814,857601,862512,156874,419242),
                 message_sent=c(1,6,2,1,1,1,2,7,3,1,1))

# merge dataset together with itself swapping from_id and to_id columns 
df.full <- merge(df,df, by.x=c("from_id","to_id"), by.y=c("to_id","from_id"),suffixes = c(".x",".y"), all=TRUE)

# fill missing values with 0
# those records will correspond to all the pairs where 
# someone did not send any messages back
df.full[is.na(df.full)] <- 0

# calculate total number of messages for each pair:
df.full$total <- df.full$message_sent.x + df.full$message_sent.y

head(df.full)
#   from_id   to_id message_sent.x message_sent.y total
# 1   91558  624227              0              1     1
# 2  156874 7134655              0              1     1
# 3  184455  624227              0              2     2
# 4  352731  624227              0              1     1
# 5  419242  713465              0              1     1
# 6  503940  624227              0              1     1
```

For very large datasets base R functions might be slow in this case you can look into using dplyr library (for most steps here it has similar functions):

```
library(dplyr)
df.full.2 <- merge(df,df               # merge dataframe and switched one
            ,by.x=c("from_id","to_id"),by.y=c("to_id","from_id")
            ,all.x=TRUE,all.y=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(message_sent.x=coalesce(message_sent.x,0),     # replace NAs with 0
         message_sent.y=coalesce(message_sent.y,0)) %>%
  mutate(total=rowSums(.[3:4]))        # calculate total number of messages

head(df2.full.2)
#  from_id   to_id message_sent.x message_sent.y total
#1   91558  624227              0              1     1
#2  156874 7134655              0              1     1
#3  184455  624227              0              2     2
#4  352731  624227              0              1     1
#5  419242  713465              0              1     1
#6  503940  624227              0              1     1
```

If it's important to have records in pairs follow each other you can also add the following code:

```
df2.full.3 <- df2.full.2 %>% 
  mutate(pair.id=sprintf("%06d%6d",pmin(from_id,to_id ),
                                   pmax(from_id,to_id ))) %>%
  arrange(pair.id) %>% select(-pair.id)

head(df2.full.3)
#  from_id   to_id message_sent.x message_sent.y total
#1   91558  624227              0              1     1
#2  624227   91558              1              0     1
#3  156874 7134655              0              1     1
#4 7134655  156874              1              0     1
#5  184455  624227              0              2     2
#6  624227  184455              2              0     2
```

There is also data.table package that is also very efficient for very large datasets:

```
library(data.table)
# convert dataframe to datatable
setDT(df)
df.full <- merge(df,df, by.x=c("from_id","to_id"), by.y=c("to_id","from_id"),
                 suffixes = c(".x",".y"), all=TRUE)

# substitute NAs with zeros
for (j in 3:4)set(df.full,which(is.na(df.full[[j]] )),j,0)

# calculate the total number of messages
df.full[, total:=message_sent.x+message_sent.y]
head(df.full)
#    from_id   to_id message_sent.x message_sent.y total
# 1:   91558  624227              0              1     1
# 2:  156874 7134655              0              1     1
# 3:  184455  624227              0              2     2
# 4:  352731  624227              0              1     1
# 5:  419242  713465              0              1     1
# 6:  503940  624227              0              1     1
```

Depending on the size of your dataset one of these methods might be more efficient than the other two.